# AvalonEdit's TextEditor : how to avoid caret offset reseting to 0

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm using ICSharpCode's AvalonEdit text editor, and I display different TextEditor controls in a TabControl after a Document list.

The WPF code of the TabControl :

```
<TabControl 
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding OpennedFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Data.Name" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <AE:TextEditor ShowLineNumbers="True" FontFamily="Consolas" Unloaded="TextEditor_Unloaded" FontSize="16" Loaded="TextEditor_Loaded" Document="{Binding Document}" SyntaxHighlighting="Python" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
```

My problem is that when you change the selectionned tab, the caret offset of the previously selected document is reset to 0, which is really annoying.

I've tried to bind the caret offset property of the text editor, but it's not a dependency property, and since I'm not really sure it would work, I did not have the courage to create an attached dependency property.

I suspect that it comes from the fact that the Document is reloaded in the text editor at the tab selection, and since the caret offseet seems to depend from the TextArea, it returns to its default value, but I still don't have any idea on how to avoid this.

Any hints ?

Comment: Don't ICSharpCode have a forum for that which will probably give you better answers?

Comment: Well it does, but considering the number of questions and responses concerning avalonEdit on SO and the relatively low activity of the IC#Code forum concerning the project, I was just giving it a try

Answer (score 0):

try saving the caret offset to a database and then set the values back during loading of the texteditor

```
this.ScrollToVerticalOffset(value1); //top offset of the editor (example line 120)
this.TextArea.Caret.Line = value2;  //value of the cursor line
```